# sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type Error in Expression

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm quite new with IntelliJ (and on this site too tbh) and have been using it for only a couple of days. When I tried to build my project this exception came up. I tried to solve the problem but to no avail. I tried to see if the same problem occured on a newly created project and yes it does. So the code I've written should have no influence on the build. Iäve also checked if there might be a problem with the sbt version but I am up to date.

This is what the error looks like. I have absolutely no clue how to solve this so any help would be very much appreciated.

```js
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Johner-Institut\.sbt\0.13\plugins
Waiting for lock on C:\Users\Johner-Institut\.ivy2\.sbt.ivy.lock to be available...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Johner-Institut\Desktop\Project\project
C:\Users\Johner-Institut\Desktop\Project\build.sbt:5: error: recursive value project needs type
lazy val `project` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
                      ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ***project*** as a name for sbt project, that's why the recursion error. Try something like:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

Comment: Thanks! It did solve the problem but new ones came up ^^'